# PC shutdowns in ~10 mins after launching Steam

Tags: windows, ubuntu, shutdown

I have a very weird problem with my PC.
Everything was working fine 4 months ago when I moved to another country and left the PC at home.

A week ago I came back and tried to play CS:GO on Windows 7. However, the PC just turned off after several minutes of playing. Since then, I have checked for viruses, run CCleaner, etc. but the problem remains: after 10 minutes in game the PC turns off.

The weird thing is that after I turn it on again, it can not launch without going into Windows restoration mode (first, normal launch, just goes off). After that, I run Steam, get the message "service is installed incorrectly" and then steam updates some data and everything becomes good. I can play for any amount of time I want. This cycle repeats every time I launch the computer.

Moreover, since I have dual boot (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14), I tried Steam on Ubuntu. The PC went off just after logging in.

Comment: This is the definite sign of a hardware problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the RAM bar from the connectors, clean the connectors on RAM with an eraser for the pencil, carefully blow off the residue and insert it into place.
2. View the condition of the thermal paste on the processor - replace it with the slightest suspicion of drying out.
3. Create bootable USB using Grub4dos (http://lazvm-comp.ru/publ/sozdanie_multizagruzochnoj_usb_fleshki_na_osnove_zagruzchika_grub4dos/1-1-0-38 , https://habrahabr.ru/post/253260/ ) c victoria ( [http: / /www.ihdd.ru/victoria](http://www.ihdd.ru/victoria) ) and memtest (http://www.memtest.org/ , http://shparg.narod.ru/index/0-6 )
4. Boot from USB and check RAM (2-3 passes) and HDD.
5. For additional HDD check I use Win7livecd (Win7 Live CD x86 / x64 by Xemom1) from the same bootable USB (same grub4dos) and HDDscan ( http://hddscan.com/ ) written on it - the program works without installation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will do it asap. Also, I tried Aida64 Extreme and it led PC to shutdown also. My current hypothesis is that the problem is in PSU. Does it make any sense?

Comment: Maybe. But, in my experience of computer repair, RAM - 45%, HDD - 40%, PSU - 15%. well, some percentage - the thermal paste